# Why would I force garbage collection after TCP client closed?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I am dealing with some legacy code that probably predates .NET 2. The library itself is custom asynchronous TCP communication layer used by our server.

There is a class there inheriting from `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` and the whole class hierarchy around it that implements dispose pattern and finalizers (the latter likely not needed).

My question is about suspicious line of code found in the method that handle TCP client disconnected event:

```
// Hack to ensure that client has disconnected
GC.Collect();
```

which is executed after calling methods disposing of our communication class hierarchy that eventually calls `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient Dispose` method.

On a 64-bit server that can serve many clients and use gigabytes of RAM these calls can be quite expensive. I could not find anything about forcing garbage collection upon TCP client disconnection?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Two things will happen after you force GC with `GC.Collect()`.

1. Memory used by unreachable objects that don't have finalizers will be reclaimed.
2. Objects that implement finalizers will be placed on finalizer queue, and the finalizers will be executed soon.

The comment suggests that `GC.Collect()` is not called to reclaim memory, but rather to execute finalizers to dispose unmanaged resources.

If `IDisposable` is used correctly, there is no need to rely on finalizers. Probably there are some `IDisposable` objects that are not `Dispose`d correctly. You'll have to find them. One way to do it is to examine what finalizers are executed. Some memory profilers can also track such objects (for example [.NET memory profiler's](http://memprofiler.com/) Dispose Tracker).

Comment: Even if I don't call GC.Collect() explicitly the finalizers will eventually get executed when garbage collection kicks in on its own? Hence, I don't see a need to call it explicitly unless I really need to dispose of resources right now...

Comment: @SlobodanSavkovic Exactly. You can try it - there is even a chance the problem was already fixed, but the 'hack' still stayed in the code.

Comment: Finalizers are a fragile mechanism. As long as your objects dispose method is properly implemented and uses `GC.SupressFinalize` in order to remove them from the f-reachabale queue, there's no need for `GC.Collect`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You're right, but even if `Dispose` is implemented correctly, it's useless if it's not called. In this case it seems that for some objects it was not called, and the quick and dirty solution was to force GC to make finalizers run. The OP is aware that it's not a good solution, but wants to know why the original developer decided to use it. It's legacy code - it means it's probably running somewhere in production. It's necessary to understand it well (especially the "hacks") before making any changes.